# Pivot Table to Reorganize Data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have data in the below format

[image]

However, I need to convert it into the below format using pivot tables or other formuals such as

[image]

where 2015 row is just split by months (divided by 12). Kindly help me with a logic that I can use. Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,
Navs

Comment: What have to tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data has a lot of IDs and years, a pivot table is the quickest way to get your first two columns, but the monthly breakdown will need to be done using formulas (e.g. index/match to pick up the FY value and divide by 12).